# UrlFetchApp DNS error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am writing a javascript in the Google spreadsheets and trying to fetch a URL. When i run curl on the same URL I am able to get it working. But when i try to use UrlFetchApp from javascript I get DNS error. Below is my code sample . Am I missing something ?

```
function upload() {
    Logger.log("hello, ");
    var headers = {
       'Content-Length' : 0
    };
    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'useIntranet': true,
        'validateHttpsCertificates': false,
         'contentType': 'text/xml'
     };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://localhost:8787/test/v2/feed", options);
   Logger.log("fetched data");
   Logger.log(response);
 }
```

Comment: The GET method also throws error? Your sending a POST with XML but with no payload.

Comment: I tried adding 'payload' : 'feed:testData' to the options and still i get the same error.

Comment: I also tried using GET instead of POST. I still get the DNS error.

Comment: When I change 'useIntranet' : false, then I don't get DNS error but there is no result as well. The response is empty. I don't think the request is even making the API call in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085768/urlfetchapp-woes

Answer (score 7):

This can't work. The UrlFetchApp is executing from a Google server, which isn't on the same network as your machine, so when it tries to find your server running on localhost it can't find it.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am accessing some other API which is on a dedicated server and can be accessed through postman and curl from any machine. Still I am getting same error.