# How to run App script function locally using js or python?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function copyFolderContents_(source, target) {
  // Iterate files in source folder
  const filesIterator = source.getFiles()
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    const file = filesIterator.next()

    // Make a copy of the file keeping the same name
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target)
  }
}

const toCopy = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
const copyInto = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
const newFolder = copyInto.createFolder(toCopy.getName())
copyFolderContents_(toCopy, newFolder)
```

Is it possible to let this run in my local machine?
The  [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) seems to be just controlling how the app script runs instead of letting you run the getFolderById makeCopy functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run app script function from website/localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472349/run-app-script-function-from-website-localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apps Script is run in google cloud servers, so you cannot run it directly in your local machine by default. Alternatively, you can access the functionality via APIs.

Basically, `getFolderById` and `makeCopy` are just wrappers for specific Drive APIs for it to be used easily on Apps Script.

To do the same thing above, you can use a combination of [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Check [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) for more info.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that `makeCopy ` is also a wrapper