# possible to run a Apps Script from Google Drive instead of script.google.com?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to create a "Apps Script" on a Windows PC for example an copy it to Google Drive.

Idea is create a Script with import from a Source of the Windows PC for example
and run this that got the result in google contacts.

Because can not open/edit the "Apps Script" on google drive.... only see a "link" to the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run app script function from website/localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472349/run-app-script-function-from-website-localhost)

Comment: You can access google apis using languages other than apps script (such as from a python script). I'd suggest the people api and people.connections.list as a potential source. The downside is that you have to do the authentication step.