# How to request internal API in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a project in GCP with some internal APIs (in VMs), Databases, and so on.
Now, I'm trying to create a GAS to obtain data from one of those internal APIs (Druid, in my case) to print some data in a Google Spreadsheet.

My point here is that I link the GAS to my GCP project, expecting to be able to connect to my internal IP (10.1.0.x) which is in a VPC, shared with the default one. So, if I start a new VM attached to the default network, I could be able to ping and connect to it. Seems reasonable.

But, when I execute the GAS function, the following pice of code fails: `UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://10.1.0.3:8082/druid/v2/?pretty', options);`.

Should I configure something else in the GCP project to be able to connect to internal APIs?
Should I change the way and use another GCP service to do so?

Any help would be more than appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UrlFetchApp unable to access localhost resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085768/urlfetchapp-unable-to-access-localhost-resource)

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported in Apps Script. You could request a feature request in the bug tracker. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features

Answer (score 0):

### Internal APIs run client-side and need to be incorporated within JavaScript code.

Within Apps Script you can run JavaScript code, if you deploy your project as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

You can then either embed the JS code within the [HTML file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) attached to the project, or directly insert it within the `<script></script>` tags within [`HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(String)).